# Can't get modal to display unique information from divs of a single class

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events

I'm a bit of a beginner and trying to create a modal that is triggered by mouseenter/mouseleave event handlers tied to a single class that is attached to multiple div blocks, but uses javascript  to grab unique title and paragraph info from attributes on each div when the mouse is over it. Is this possible or do I have to create individual modals for each div to achieve this?
(I tentatively set it up to display the info from the first box on all of them to show generally what i'm going for)

https://codepen.io/admaloch/pen/yLKWWew

```
boxes.forEach((box) => {
  box.addEventListener("mouseenter", function (e) {
    modalContainer.classList.remove("display-none");
    modalTitle.innerText = titleInfo[0].title;
    modalParagraph.innerText = dataContent[0].dataset.content;
  });

  box.addEventListener("mouseleave", function (e) {
    modalContainer.classList.add("display-none");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but you can just access these attributes through `box`

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".block");

const modalContainer = document.querySelector(".modal");
const modalTitle = document.querySelector(".modal-title");
const modalParagraph = document.querySelector(".modal-paragraph");

boxes.forEach((box) => {
  box.addEventListener("mouseenter", function (e) {
    modalContainer.classList.remove("display-none");
    modalTitle.innerText = box.title;
    modalParagraph.innerText = box.dataset.content;
  });

  box.addEventListener("mouseleave", function (e) {
    modalContainer.classList.add("display-none");
  });
});
```

```css
.block-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.block {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.display-none {
  display: none;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  left: 35%;
  top: 10vh;
  border-radius: 14px;
}

.modal-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.modal-title,
.modal-paragraph {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block-container">
    <div class="block" title="1" data-content="Info for the 1st box"></div>
    <div class="block" title="2" data-content="Info for the 2nd box"></div>
    <div class="block" title="3" data-content="Info for the 3rd box"></div>
    <div class="block" title="4" data-content="Info for the 4th box"></div>
    <div class="block" title="5" data-content="Info for the 5th box"></div>
    <div class="block" title="6" data-content="Info for the 6th box"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal display-none">
    <div class="modal-info">
      <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
      <p class="modal-paragraph"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an index in forEach and use that index instead of titleInfo[0]

```
boxes.forEach((box, index) => {
  box.addEventListener("mouseenter", function (e) {
    modalContainer.classList.remove("display-none");
    modalTitle.innerText = titleInfo[index].title;
    modalParagraph.innerText = dataContent[index].dataset.content;
  });

  box.addEventListener("mouseleave", function (e) {
    modalContainer.classList.add("display-none");
  });
});
```